# Kendo Editor for jQuery. Backcolor reset

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have an application that utilizes the Kendo editor for the text area. Within the configuration, we've successfully employed the 'backcolor' option. However, our end-users have expressed a need for a feature that allows them to reset the background color for selected text. They're looking for either a reset button or a transparent option within the palette accessible through the 'backcolor' button. Is there a way to implement this functionality?

Below the code:

```
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
<script>
$("#editor").kendoEditor({
    tools: [{
        name: "foreColor"
    }]
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom palette or use a gradient tool, as shown in the [API](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/editor/configuration/tools.palette), but besides making a custom tool for handling backColor I dont't think there is an option to add a "reset color". Maybe define a palette and add the background color you use to it, so users can select it, something along the lines in [this example](https://dojo.telerik.com/EQaNIqIW).